# expected resource type id in TextView Element android id issue

Tags: android-layout

this is my xml file where i create a single TextView..with id welcome
       i tried a lot but not get proper result..

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  >
            // mainactivity.java class

       TextView newView;// declare object of textview
       @Override
        newView=(TextView) findViewById(R.layout.welcome);
     }
```

// error here expected resources of type id.(R.layout.welcome)//it show error here expected type resource id. kindly help i am new android

Answer (score 0):

you must use the id of your textview (android:id="@+id/welcome") i.e. welcome.
So, instead of using R.layout.welcome, use R.id.welcome, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing :

```
newView=(TextView) findViewById(R.layout.welcome);
```

Write this :

```
newView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
```